# Seam 2.2GA + JBoss AS 5.1GA + Postgres 8.4

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

**Sorry for the big wall of text, but its mostly logs**

**Thx for any help in any of my problems**

I've been trying to get help from Seam forums, but in vain.

I'm trying this Setup mentioned in the title, but unsuccessfully.

I have it all installed correctly and the problems start with the seam-gen.

**This is my build.properties**

```
#Generated by seam setup
#Sat Aug 29 19:12:18 BRT 2009
hibernate.connection.password=abc123
workspace.home=/home/rgoytacaz/workspace
hibernate.connection.dataSource_class=org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource
model.package=com.atom.Commerce.model
hibernate.default_catalog=PostgreSQL
driver.jar=/home/rgoytacaz/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
action.package=com.atom.Commerce.action
test.package=com.atom.Commerce.test
database.type=postgres
richfaces.skin=glassX
glassfish.domain=domain1
hibernate.default_schema=Core
database.drop=n
project.name=Commerce
hibernate.connection.username=postgres
glassfish.home=C\:/Program Files/glassfish-v2.1
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
jboss.domain=default
project.type=ear
icefaces.home=
database.exists=y
jboss.home=/srv/jboss-5.1.0.GA
driver.license.jar=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:postgresql\:Atom
icefaces=n
```

**./seam create-project works okay, but when I try generate-entities, I get the following...**

```
generate-model:
     [echo] Reverse engineering database using JDBC driver /home/rgoytacaz/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
     [echo] project=/home/rgoytacaz/workspace/Commerce
     [echo] model=com.atom.Commerce.model
[hibernate] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JDBC Configuration (for reverse engineering)
[hibernate] 1. task: hbm2java (Generates a set of .java files)
[hibernate] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
[hibernate] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[javaformatter] Java formatting of 4 files completed. Skipped 0 file(s).
```

**this is problem no.1. How do I fix this? What is this? I had to do this in eclipse. It worked.**

Then I import the seam-gen created project into eclipse, and deploy to JBoss 5.1. While my servers start I've noticed the following..

```
03:18:56,405 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: alter table PostgreSQL.atom.productsculturedetail add constraint FKBD5D849BC0A26E19 foreign key (culture_Id) references PostgreSQL.atom.cultures
03:18:56,406 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "postgresql.atom.productsculturedetail"
03:18:56,407 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: alter table PostgreSQL.atom.productsculturedetail add constraint FKBD5D849BFFFC9417 foreign key (product_Id) references PostgreSQL.atom.products
03:18:56,408 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "postgresql.atom.productsculturedetail"*
03:18:56,408 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] schema update complete
```

**Problem no.2. What is this cross-database references?**

What about this..

```
03:18:55,089 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 8.4 JDBC3 (build 701)
```

**Problem no.3 I've said in the build.properties to use JDBC4 driver, I don't know why seam insists to use JDBC3 driver. Where do I change this?**

When I go into http://localhost:5443/Commerce and try to browse the auto-generated CRUD UI.

I get this error.. **Error reading 'resultList' on type com.atom.Commerce.action.ProductsList_$$_javassist_seam_2**

And this is what is showing in my server logs...

```
03:34:00,828 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: 
    select
        products0_.product_Id as product1_0_,
        products0_.active as active0_ 
    from
        PostgreSQL.atom.products products0_ limit ?
03:34:00,848 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 0A000
03:34:00,849 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "postgresql.atom.products"
  Position: 81
03:34:00,871 SEVERE [viewhandler] Error Rendering View[/ProductsList.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /ProductsList.xhtml: Error reading 'resultList' on type com.atom.Commerce.action.ProductsList_$$_javassist_seam_2
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

**Problem no.4 What is going on here? Cross-database references?**

Thx for any help in any of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

You *did* receive a few answers on the Seam forums ([here](http://www.seamframework.org/Community/SeamgenGenerateDoesNotWorkProperly#comment92470) and [here](http://www.seamframework.org/Community/Seam22GAJBossAS51GAPostgres84#comment93887)), but you didn't follow up. Anyway, all these are actually caused by one problem:

1. As Stuart Douglas [told you](http://www.seamframework.org/Community/Seam22GAJBossAS51GAPostgres84#comment93889), you shouldn't use a catalog when connecting to PostgreSQL. To fix this, replace the property "`hibernate.default_catalog=PostgreSQL`" in your properties file by the property: "`hibernate.default_catalog.null=`", so that your file looks like this:

   ```
   ...
   model.package=com.atom.Commerce.model
   hibernate.default_catalog.null=      # <-- This is the replaced property
   driver.jar=/home/rgoytacaz/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
   ...
   ```

   You should be able to use `seam generate-entities` fine afterwards (assuming the rest of your configuration is correct). I'd recommend doing the generation into a clean folder.
2. Cross-database references is when a query tries to access two or more different databases. PostgreSQL does not support this, and thus complains when there is more than 1 period in the table name, so in **`PostgreSQL.`**`atom.productsculturedetail`, the bold part should be removed. Hibernate adds this prefix when you tell it to use a default catalog, which we already fixed in step 1 above (by telling it not to use a catalog), so this problem should be fixed after you regenerate your entities.

   (Note that this is effectively the same as what Stuart Douglas told you, that you should remove the `catalog="PostgreSQL"` attribute in the annotations on your entity classes.)
3. When you specified the `postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar` file in the properties file, this didn't mean that the driver supports JDBC4. Although the name of the file would suggest so, the driver's website [clearly states that](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/#features) *"The driver provides a reasonably complete implementation of the **JDBC 3** specification"*. This shouldn't be a problem for you, as you're not using the driver directly (or at least you're not supposed to). The driver is sufficient for Hibernate to fulfill its requirements and provide the required functionality.
4. This issue is caused by the same problem above. Hibernate is unable to read data from the database because of the incorrect query. Fixing the catalog problem should fix this issue.